# git push commit larger than 100 mb

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to push my commit but it takes too much time and when I use GitHub desktop application it tells me my commit is larger than 100 MB and it's true my commit is 128 MB , I tried gitlf but I have too many files and changes in existing files in Github.
is there any way to push this commit the normal way?

Comment: Are all modifications to a single file? Even still, is it absolutely necessary to push a single commit?

Comment: no, I modified many files , actually, I'm trying to remove some files and push two commits but it's still larger than 100 mb

Comment: git is designed for text files, not binaries

Comment: Running `git push` *is* the "normal" way (and the only way Git itself provides). Git*Hub* (not Git itself, but rather, the folks at GitHub) place limits on file and repo sizes.